# Oracle weblogic server stop failed

Tags: java, weblogic

When i debug my application in net beans, oracle weblogic server displays below exception in console.

```
Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ...
This Exception occurred at Wed Oct 16 16:56:01 IST 2013.
javax.naming.AuthenticationException
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
File "D:\Weblogic\Middleware_1\base_domain\shutdown.py", line 3, in ?
File "<iostream>", line 22, in connect
File "<iostream>", line 648, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect :
User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated. 
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace
```

my application uses `oracle weblogic server` and results will published into `orale Bi publisher`

My shutdown.py:

```
wlsUserID = java.lang.System.getenv('wlsUserID') wlsPassword = java.lang.System.getenv('wlsPassword') connect(username=wlsUserID, password=wlsPassword, url='t3://localhost:7001', adminServerName='AdminServer') shutdown('AdminServer','Server', ignoreSessions='true') exit()
```

Comment: my application uses  oracle weblogic server and results will published into orale Bi publisher

Comment: Can you post your shutdown.py? And whati is valid user name in your server? - `User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.`

Comment: wlsUserID = java.lang.System.getenv('wlsUserID')  
wlsPassword = java.lang.System.getenv('wlsPassword')  
connect(username=wlsUserID, password=wlsPassword, url='t3://localhost:7001', adminServerName='AdminServer')  
shutdown('AdminServer','Server', ignoreSessions='true')  
exit()

Comment: username:weblogic pwd:password123

Comment: What is port number for AdminServer?

Comment: 7001 is he port number

Comment: Are you use only one server (AdminServer)?

Comment: edited boot.properties with above username and pwd. but the problem is weblogic server is not stopping –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `WebLogic` `AdminServer` is locked when you try shutdown. Can you delete `.lok` files in your `AdminServer` directory or check `Lock & Edit` function in WebLogic console?

**EDIT**: If not able to delete `.lok` files and you want to stop `WebLogic` you can use the [nmkill](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1066305) command. I don't know what type of OS you use. I always use `kill -9`command in Unix to stop WebLogic. To start `WebLogic` server you first need to start `NodeManager` and after the `AdminServer`. Here is [nmStart](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1106005) command.

Comment: I'm not able to delete .lok files and also Lock and edit option is not working

Comment: will you help on this issue

Comment: i am using windows. will u give me windows commands,so that i can resolve

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will have to define your userid and password in boot.properties file in security folder of your Admin/Managed Server. In your case the location will be "D:\Weblogic\Middleware_1\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security". If the file boot.properties is not existent create one in that location and mention the following in plain text:

username=weblogic

password=password123

If the server startup is successful it will be encrypted automatically.

Comment: edited boot.properties with above username and pwd. but the problem is weblogic server is not stopping

Comment: Check if there are any options misconfigured with the security tab of the Admin Server

Answer (score 0):

We too faced the same issue earlier. Just i reloaded the .bash_profile or .bash_rc files where i have placed the `JAVA`, `ORACLE_HOME` paths. After re-loading the files, the issues is resolved and I am able to shutdown the weblogic server.